# Didn't find class "com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have recently launched an app that has anonymous and google login enabled on firebase(atm google sign in is not activated in the app).

Firebase Crashlytics has some crash reports with "Didn't find class "com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"" on some devices but my app has nothing to with facebook or facebook login. I checked AndroidManifest or buildgraddle files and there is absolutely nothing regarding facebook login.

When I used Search Everywhere function in Android Studio with "facebook", it brings implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.0.1' since it includes methods regarding all login types available on Firebase.

Crash occured on devices GCE x86 phone (Android 9), Pixel 6 (Android 12) and Pixel 5 (Android 11)

App doesn't crash on my and my families phones Galaxy A7, A31, A71 (Android 7, 11, 11 respectively)

All crash reports look pretty much below:

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Didn't find class "com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~Ko9ZjzfmE8iRzY8kL5QL1Q==/com.hashi_daily_bridge_puzzles-HJbJv6IA69g_I2HGK8O82A==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~Ko9ZjzfmE8iRzY8kL5QL1Q==/com.hashi_daily_bridge_puzzles-HJbJv6IA69g_I2HGK8O82A==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~Ko9ZjzfmE8iRzY8kL5QL1Q==/com.hashi_daily_bridge_puzzles-HJbJv6IA69g_I2HGK8O82A==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Ko9ZjzfmE8iRzY8kL5QL1Q==/com.hashi_daily_bridge_puzzles-HJbJv6IA69g_I2HGK8O82A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity (AppComponentFactory.java:95)
androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity (CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1253)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3335)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3595)
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2066)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7664)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:592)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I could not find any solution on internet, worst part is I can't reproduce the crash on my phone

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.